# MemoryError in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

having some in a jupyter notebook, that reads images into my memory. Unfortunately I get an MemoryError after reading about 2 GB into my memory (which is 64 GB).

Anyone an idea why is that? Is it possible to assign more memory to jupyter notebook?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is running out of memory, I guess that's something in the OS restricting it. You can see https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/713

Comment: If you say "after reading 2GB", do you mean that you have read 2GB of image files (size on disk) or that you prgram is using 2GB of memory at that point? Because if you have compressed images, they might get much larger when imported into memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my special case, the problem was that I used a 32 bit version of python. I was wondering, because the script ran earlier without any problems on a 64 bit version.